# Change Emacs theme with mode

Tags: emacs

I would like to switch from 'solarized-dark (with my theme by default) to 'solarized-light when typing LATEX or Markdown.
I'm using Emacs 24 and solarized from https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized.

In my custom.el, I wrote the following lines :

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path (make-plugin-path "color-theme-solarized"))
(load-theme 'solarized 1)

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
      (lambda (frame)
        (set-frame-parameter frame 'background-mode 'light))
      )
```

But it doesn't work properly, i.e. loading a .md file does not make Emacs switch from 'dark to 'light solarized theme.

Comment: You want to look into buffer-local themes and `face-remap-add-relative` -- there are at least a few threads that already exist on this subject.

Comment: Duplicate Q&A: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44887/454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (set-frame-parameter (window-frame) 'background-mode 'dark)
    (enable-theme 'solarized)))
```

The main changes are calling `window-frame` to get the current frame and then `enable-theme` to make it active.

Comment: @Win thanks, `enable-theme` did not work for me, but `(load-theme 'spacemacs-light t nil)))` worked. The only thing is, the light theme does not switch back to dark when I exit the mode.